# Deploying Node js Server and React js App with Firebase

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

How do I set-up/deploy an existing node.js (back end) server on Firebase and how do I deploy a front end reactjs app on Firebase? The front end leverages APIs on the node.js server.

I can only find resources that will help me do one or the other but not both.

Comment: Firebase is a DB technology and does not host Node.js servers or static web pages as far as I know. You should look at hosting like Heroku.com for this. The server and react spa are hosted on heroku and read data from firebase.

Comment: Firebase offers many services... not just DB. I know I can host at least the react app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to run quite some Node.js code in [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) and [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions), it is not a drop-in replacement.

So if you want to simply run your existing Node.js back-end, you're likely better off looking elsewhere.

Comment: Downvoter: can you please explain why you downvoted my answer?

Comment: Hi Frank. I can, however, host my react app and use another service (that's not Firebase) to deploy my node js back end server; right? I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes" but I'm a noob at deploying web applications so I want to make sure.

Comment: Sure thing. And many node scripts can probably be converted into Cloud Functions too. It's just not a drop-in replacement, and you'll have to map the functionality to Cloud Functions' paradigms.